# How to always display overflow-y in fullscreen mode

Tags: css, html

As soon as I activate the fullscreen-mode, the y overflow vanishes.

Chrome developer tools are showing this:

[image]

As you can see, I overwrote the :root:-webkit-full-screen-ancestor in my css, and my style is shown as the selected style. 
Nevertheless, the overall state is "hidden".
Chrome, IE and Firefox are showing this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error did only occur using the implemented fullscreen button. 
It resulted from

```
document.body.requestFullScreen()
```

Replacing it with

```
document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
```

solved it...

Comment: You are a lifesaver, a true hero! Thanks for coming back and posting your answer!

Comment: Hey also, I was just reading about Empires in Space. We should compare notes. I'm working on Neptune's Pride.